# Removing "[crap-like-this]" from strings using bash parameter expansion?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

If I have the following `$STRING`

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.[ddd].eee.fff.[ggg].hhh
```

is there any way, using bash parameter expansion, to echo the following

```
aaa.bbb..ccc.eee.fff..hhh
```

That is, remove all occurrences of square brackets and everything inside those brackets? Everything I've tried ends up either removing everything in the string after the first left bracket or removing the brackets but leaving behind everything inside the brackets.

Comment: Could you verify the output in this post again?

Answer (score 1):

Requires `shopt -s extglob`:

```
bash-4.1# STRING='aaa.bbb.ccc.[ddd].eee.fff.[ggg].hhh'

bash-4.1# echo "${STRING//\[+([^\]])\]}"
aaa.bbb.ccc..eee.fff..hhh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s extglob

STRING='[asd].aaa.bbb.ccc.[ddd].eee.fff.[ggg].hhh.[asd]'
printf '%s\n' "${STRING//@(.\[*([^]])]|\[*([^]])]?(.))/}"
```

would give:

```
aaa.bbb.ccc.eee.fff.hhh
```